# Run Windows Service after particular time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created windows service. I need to run that automatically after 2 minutes. For that i have called System.Timers.Timer under **OnStart** and set the interval to 2 minutes (after converting from millseconds) and made than enabled as true

I have also made Timer Stopped and made that enabled as false in **OnStop** Method.

Is that ok or i'm missing anything? Let me know

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set`Timer.AutoReset=true` after `InitializedComponent()` or in your `OnStart` function before you set `Timer.Enabled = true` and **do remember you need to define your Timer in Class level**

See [Timer.AutoReset Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx)

Comment: I have set the autoreset to false before making timer enabled. Is anything else required?

Comment: @Romil, that is all you needed, if you only want to run it once.

Comment: @Bolu: "run it once" means once every 2 minutes (as mentioned in my questions) OR only ONCE?

Comment: @Romil, if you need to run it every 2 minutes, you need to set AutoReset to TRUE as I mentioned in my answer (not to FALSE as in your comment above).